# How do I define part of a Go struct as a string of JSON?

Tags: arrays, json, go, struct, unmarshalling

I have a JSON API I'm attempting to consume with a simple Go application, and return an array of JSON strings, which will be inserted into a database for later consumption.  The JSON model looks like this:

```
 {
    "sites": {
        "count": 123,
        "site": [
            {
                "id": 111,
                "name": "abc"
            },
            {
                "id": 222,
                "name": "def"
            },
            {
                "id": 333,
                "name": "ghi"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The desired result is an array that looks like:

```
{"id": 111, "name": "abc"}
{"id": 222, "name": "def"}
{"id": 333, "name": "ghi"}
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to define a struct that stops unmarshalling at a certain point in the struct definition.  Is there a way to just dump the contents of the []struct into a string for each element in the struct array, instead of defining the contents of the sub-struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `json.RawMessage`:

```
type Sites struct {
   Count int `json:"count"`
   SiteArr []json.RawMessage `json:"site"`
}
```

When you unmarshal the data into the above struct, each element of `SiteArr` will contain the raw JSON message for each element, and you can get the string value from that using `string(sites.SiteArr[i])`

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.